# Get length/size of json data

Tags: json, datalength

I have use the following codes to get my json data with certain nodes.

```
console.log(Object.keys(data.Top["person"]).length);
```

It is work fine in following structure of json data array:

```
data:{"Top":{"person":[{"A":"a","B":"b"},{"A":"a","B":"b"}]}}
```

However when the person only have one nodes, it always show the answer `2` to me, it should be answer `1`.

```
data:{"Top":{"person":{"A":"a","B":"b"}}}
```

Is it possible to solve this error?

Comment: try `data.top.person.length` @Elice

Comment: same problem, for more than 1 nodes, it is work fine and return '2' to me, but for data only have one nodes, it return 'undefined' to me

Answer (score 0):

`length` property is supported by type array.

`data:{"Top":{"person":[{"A":"a","B":"b"},{"A":"a","B":"b"}]}}` in case of this `person` is array enclosed with `[ ]`

Where as for `data:{"Top":{"person":{"A":"a","B":"b"}}}` `person` is just an object. Hence `length` is `undefined` for it.

If you are creating json out of string or formatting it make sure to include `[` and `]` for `person` attribute.

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/d6pqnckh/

Also use JSON formatter to test JSON structure.

**UPDATE**
Since you are not sure of JSON structure. What you could do is before accessing length of `person` check if it is an array or object.

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(data.Top.person) === '[object Array]')
      alert(data.Top.person.length);
      //It is an array
else 
     alert("I AM OBJECT"); //It is of an object type
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wys7awuz/

**To make it an array regardless** https://jsfiddle.net/ofkboh6k/

```
 var p = data.Top.person;
 delete data.Top.person;
 data.Top.person = [];
 data.Top.person.push(p);
 alert(data.Top.person.length);
```

Include this in else part of condition. It will make it an array.

Comment: so is it any possible way to convert the json data to force it become array when it is only one data array?

Answer (score 0):

`length` works for type array.

change your JSON to

```
data:{"Top":{"person":[{"A":"a","B":"b"}]}}
```

Comment: so is it any possible way to convert the json data to force it become array when it is only one data array?